# Storing data in html dynamically (html5)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am creating a dynamic div in html which consists of multiple checkboxes. All these checkboxes and divs are being dynamically added to the html. I need to store some data about each div in the html to be accessed by javascript later. Can anyone show me an example where data can be added and retrieved dynamically in a div? I know HTML5 allows it and there are some other hacks to do it, but I am having trouble with syntax I guess.

Comment: You may want to look into [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: It really depends on how you want to go about it. You can always store stuff in `data` attributes like @Whymarrh said, or regular non-standard attributes if you don't care about compliance, but you could also do `PHP`/`ASP`/`CGI` if you want stuff from server-side, or just plain `JavaScript`/`jQuery` if all the data will be changed on the client side and no new data will come from the server. You could even do it from `AJAX`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it using JavaScript:

```
SomeClass.someVariable = document.getElementById('divid');
```

Otherwise if you mean to access custom data that has to used as attribute in your HTML tags then use

```
data-XXX = 'YYY';
```

And access it with JS:

```
document.getElementById('divid').dataset.XXX;
```

Answer (score 2):

This post explains data-* attributes.

You can create custom attributes within your divs like this:

```
<div id="div1" data-text="Hello. This is a custom attribute."></div>
```

Notice the `data-` prefix. this is absolutely necessary.
Then (using jQuery) you can access the custom attribute:

```
$('#div1').data('text'); => "Hello. This is a custom attribute."
```

So using this you can do stuff like:

```
if($('#div1').data('text') != "FreddieBobman"){
    alert("HI!");
} else {
    alert("Forever Alone!");
}
```

The above example will alert "HI!" because `$('#div1').data('text')` does not contain 
FreddieBobman, it is in fact "Hello. This is a custom attribute."

To create these attributes use the following:

```
$('#div1').attr('data-name', 'value');
```

Our div with id of div1 now has another attribute, data-name, and the attribute has a value of value. Of course, you can change the value of attributes as well:

```
<div id="div1" data-text="Hello. This is a custom attribute."></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        $('#div1').attr('data-text', 'This is cool.');
    }());
</script>
```

Now the div has `data-text` equal to "This is cool.", not "Hello. This is a custom attribute."

Answer (score 0):

It is Obtain by the `data attributes` that you add dynamically to the elements ,And retrieve when you want !

**SET Attribute :**

```
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('data','my_data');
        div.innerHTML = "I am a div";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**GET Attribute :**

```
        div.getAttribute('data')
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/JTM9b/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use attributes for your html tags. Also, in html5 you can also use custom attributes

Comment: Why not put your references in your post?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to add or retrieve data from div tags dynamically?

Using javascript function you can simply get corresponding div element using its id,

```
var container = document.getElementById('your_element_id');
```

Then you can add what you want.

```
var stringToAdd = "<p>something you want to add</p>";
container.innerHTML = stringToAdd;
```

Also you can use a different class with different features and set it as your div class.
you need to add your features inside style tag under your class name. Then,

```
var elementID = document.getElementById(ID);
elementID.className ="your_new_class_name";
```

or you can set attributes for your tag.

```
elementID.setAttribute('display','inline');
```

Using jquery with javascript,

```
var elementID = document.getElementById(ID);
$(elementID).replaceWith( "<p>something you want to replace</p>" );
```

using class name or id you can dynamically append content using,

```
var stringToAdd = "<p>something you want to add</p>";
$(".your_class_name").append(stringToAdd);
```

also you can remove whole element using,

```
$(elementID).remove();
```